# java.lang.IllegalAccessError in Atomic Kotlin Exercise Submissions

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I am a newbie to learning Kotlin, and I take the Atomic Kotlin course in Intellij Idea with EduTools plugin

When I checking for any exercises(except exercise 1-2 in hello,world section), I encountered this error:

```
Failed to launch checking

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x4a0535bd) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x4a0535bd

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 1s

 Task :util:compileKotlin NO-SOURCE
 Task :util:compileJava NO-SOURCE
 Task :util:processResources NO-SOURCE
 Task :util:classes UP-TO-DATE
 Task :compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
 Task :compileJava FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

And check is failed, despite my submission and the answer are identical.

How can I fix this problem?

I use:

- IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.3
- Gradle v. 7.1.1
- JDK v.16.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Try to select JDK 11 as Gradle JVM in **Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle**.
Also, select JDK 11 as Project SDK in **File | Project Structure**.

If you don't have one, deploy JDK 11 as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/download-jdk/).